# Convert uint8 value of a pixel in the grayscale image to binary value in matlab

Tags: matlab, binary

I have an grayscale image, in grayscale images, each pixel have a uint8 value. for example when i use `myImage(2, 3)` , then i received a value between 0 to 255 corresponding pixel value. now i want convert this value to a binary array of 8 bits. for example : if `myImage(2, 3)` is equivalent to 15, then i want converted value of this pixel be `00001111`.

Comment: im2bw(), but why 00001111, if i may ask? this will go to 0 and 1

Comment: Oh i get it, not binary image, but the binary representation? what is the purpose? maybe if you explained why you want to do this I can tell you why you don't need to? If it's purely for display then http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html

Comment: thanks  AK4749, i want work with 8 bits of a pixel, for example exchange of two half of these 8 bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dec2bin(15, 8)` returns `00001111`, as a string. Here, 8 specifies the minimum length of the binary string.

See [here](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/dec2bin.html) for full info.

If you want it as a matrix, you could do something like this:

```
binstring = dec2bin(pixelVal, 8);
m = str2num(binstring(:))';
```

Which, with a pixelVal of 15, results in `m = [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1]`.

Comment: thanks Junuxx, but dec2bin function convert decimal to binary number in string. i want a matrix 1*8 and working with this bits

Comment: @hamed: I see, well that's just a few lines extra. Updated my answer.

Comment: yes, i have this idea in my mind, but i want use one function and not use any loop

Comment: Also eliminated the loop. But maybe you should have a look at [bitshift](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/bitshift.html), it might allow you to do the tricks you seem to want to do without doing the conversions to binary numbers yourself.